# How to use nc send udp packet to windows 7?

Tags: bash, udp, raspberry-pi

I need send some udp packet consquently from raspberry pi to windows 7,in windows side,i use UDPclient to listen any udp data ,that is the code :

```
        byte[] data = new byte[1024];
        string input, stringData;
        UdpClient server = new UdpClient("127.0.0.1", 9050);

        IPEndPoint sender = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 0);

        while (true)
        {
            data = server.Receive(ref sender);
            stringData = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(data, 0, data.Length);
            Console.WriteLine(stringData);
        }
        Console.WriteLine("Stopping client");
        server.Close();
```

and to the raspberry pi side,i want to write a bash script to do the work ,but i do not know how,
i have done some test,if i type:

```
nc -vnzu 192.168.0.104
```

the output is :connection to 192.168.0.104 9050 port [udp/*] succeeded!

and if i type :

```
 nc -4u -w1 192.168.0.104 9050
```

there is no output,it seems still no error.

if i don't use nc,just type :

```
echo -n "hello" >/dev/udp/192.168.0.104/9050
```

there is no error message show,but in windows side ,the c# progeam above does not show any receive data

so,can anybody tell me how to do this ,best in bash  script form,thank you.

Comment: According to your question your client is listening on `127.0.0.1:9050`. That address won't receive packets from the outside.

Answer (score 0):

Most bash implementations don't have `/dev/udp`/`/dev/tcp` support compiled in, so that may be the reason that isn't working for you.

Assuming you have them enabled: the problem may be a firewall configuration issue on the Windows 7 side. Check that the Windows 7 firewall is allowing inbound connections to your selected port (9050).